# How to show all dictionary in template in Django?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, ifc

I am working with IFC and I need to extract some data from a .ifc file to be displayed in the Django template.

The template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>upload</h2>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="document">
    <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    {{result}}
{% endblock %}
```

I've tried two methods:

```
    OpenIfcFile = ifcopenshell.open(filepath) #select the file
    BrowseIfcProducts = OpenIfcFile.by_type('IfcElement') #search for the attribute 'IfcElement'
    for eachproduct in BrowseIfcProducts:
        #add the .ifc searched data to dict 'context' with 'result' key 
        context['result'] =
        [
            eachproduct.is_a(),
            eachproduct.GlobalId,
            eachproduct.get_info()["type"],
            eachproduct.get_info().get("Name","error"),
        ]
return render(request, 'upload.html', context)
```

In this method, due the key 'result' doesn't change on each iteration, only the last item is stored and in my template i can't see all items.

So, to fix this problem, I concatenate the result key to a iterator (i):

```
    i = 1
    for eachproduct in BrowseIfcProducts:    
        context['{} {}'.format('result', i)] = [
            eachproduct.is_a(), 
            eachproduct.GlobalId, 
            eachproduct.get_info()["type"],
            eachproduct.get_info().get("Name","error"),
        ]
        i += 1
return render(request, 'upload.html', context)
```

But, unfortunately, nothing is displayed in the template

I'm stuck here, i don't know how can I show the data on template, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template you're referencing `{{ result }}`, however it doesn't appear there is a key for `result` in the `context` dictionary you're passing to the view.

Since your keys seem arbitrary, you may just want a list. (Or likely you can just pass the `BrowseIfcProducts` directly to the template if you dont need complex operators)

```
object_list = [[x.is_a(), z.GlobalId, x.get_info()["type"], x.get_info().get('name', 'Error')] for x in BrowseIfcProducts] 
context['results'] = object_list
```

And in the template you can use

`{{ results }}`

A small FYI- if you're using the Django Debug Toolbar, in the "Templates" section you can see all the context availble to your template- which may help for future debugging.